# Contradicting Kubo formula with momentum in literatures

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electric-current, electrical-resistance, greens-functions

Kubo formula of electrical conductivity $\sigma(q,\omega)$ can be frequency and momentum dependent in general, which includes the paramagnetic term ($j_q^\dagger\mathrm{-}j_q$ correlation function $\Pi(q,\omega)$ at finite $\omega$) and the $\omega=0$ diamagnetic term
$$\sigma_{ab}(q,\omega)=\frac{\Pi_{ab}(q,\omega)-\Pi_{ab}(q={\bf ??},\omega=0)}{\omega}.$$
However, the diamagnetic term appears not to be well documented in the literature or textbooks. Often, only the specific case of quadratic dispersion is given as $-i\frac{e^2n}{m}\delta_{ab}$. At least two contradicting versions of the above general form exist: In Eq. (18) of [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.102.165151) (open-access), it goes with $q=0$; in Eq. (41) of [this lecture note](http://newton.phy.bme.hu/%7Eszunyogh/Elszerk/Kubo.pdf), it is finite $q$. I struggled to find an error in either of them but still have no clue.

Which is the correct form? This is something very fundamental and unambiguous at all; I believe there should be a definitive answer.

Comment: Well in first paper after eq 18 they say that they do not have any $\vec{q}$ dependence since there is no magnetic field. So it does not matter.

Comment: @physshyp What special case is discussed in the later part doesn't affect my question, though.

Comment: In these kinds of formulae, very often the limits $\omega \to 0$ and $q \to 0$ do not commute. I would worry $\Pi_{ab}(0,0)$ might not be well defined in general.

Comment: @user2309840 Thanks for raising that up. Where the transport limit is concerned, one just takes $q\rightarrow0$ first; so I suppose $\Pi(0,0)$ should also be interpreted this way. For the other version with $\Pi(q,0)$, it rather assumes the opposite limit in the first place; not sure if this is suspicious.